# Setting background in XML format in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, dot42

I asked this question in `chat rooms` tagged with `Android` but it turns out they didn't encounter this before, and I cannot find specific question either on Google so I think this is a valid point to post this as a question here.

The problem is, if I refer to an XML file format as `android:background="@drawable/bg"`, I got compilation error saying:

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/bg').
```

But if I put some file like for e.g ".png" or ".jpg", it compiles well. Sounds like it does not recognize the file as a valid `drawable`? Either if I put that file in other location, its just don't compile.

This is the `bg.xml` contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners android:radius="2dp" />
  <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="#fff" />
</shape>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I've create the "res" and "drawable" folders by myself because it's not default in this kind of environment.

Comment: Is `bg.xml` located in `/res/drawable` folder (no qualifiers)?

Comment: @Karakuri Yep. But I created the "res" and "drawable" folders myself

Comment: That should be fine still. Have you tried cleaning the project or restarting Eclipse? (Eclipse is a bit wonky sometimes...) Failing that, maybe show us the XML of the file where this is used?

Comment: @Karakuri I did try cleaning it again and again, but this error won't go away. I'm using `VS2010` not `Eclipse` :)

Comment: where you are setting this background..?

Comment: Are there any Android tools for that environment? If not, are you sure your resources are being compiled into the apk?

Comment: @wqrahd In other xml file (`mainlayout.xm1`)

Comment: @Karakuri Yep all resources compiled into ".apk" only problem is that if I make a drawable resource with an ".xml" format in it.

Comment: have you put solid in your xml..?..<solid android:color="@color/color_white" />

Comment: you have not fill your shape.

Comment: Hey I just tried your posted code. No error is coming. Its working fine.

Comment: @wqrahd Not working :(

Comment: close and re run your eclipse.

Comment: @Dig In what environment did you try this? I'm working on VS2010 with dot42 for reminding.

Comment: @wqrahd I'm using VS2010 :(

Comment: @mr5 i just read your tag.

Comment: @wqrahd Yes I'm glad you noticed it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is something preventing you from using either Eclipse or Android Studio? i think something about your environment prevents drawables defined with XML from being properly compiled/included in the APK, but I have no way to test.

Comment: @Karakuri Nothing in `Eclipse` but I just wanted to try this one out. Anyway, I might switch from eclipse if I ever encounter another simple annoying problem.

Comment: What is the value of the build action property of bg.xml?

Comment: @Frank Yay! Thanks. It was previously `Content` then I changed it to `DrawableResource`. I think it's not included in your documentation that's why I didn't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Build Action property of item bg.xml to DrawableResource.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this problem in VS 2013. Then i do this..
In the solution explorer click on drawable folder and check if your image exists here or not. If not then right click on drawable folder and click add-> existing item and then add your Image here.